# Locating British National Grid Eastings/Northings in ArcGIS Pro i.e. ArcMap Go To XY equivalent?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro is there a way to search for Eastings and Northings for Britain, similar to the Go to XY in ArcMap?

Comment: You need to change the Display Units http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/map-units-location-units-and-display-units.htm

Comment: @Mapperz I think that is useful if you just want to mouse over the map to locate that coordinate but it does not seem to help with using the XY Provider of the Locate pane, which to me seems to be the workflow equivalent to ArcMap's Go To XY tool.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using the Locate tool from the MAP tab and typing in coordinates based on a spatial reference system works fine for latitude and longitude:

[image]

You can then right-click on the result to Zoom To or Pan To.

I got this from a [similar question asked and answered on GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/158947) which came up when I googled for it but that does not mention British National Grid (and seems to be for UTM zones instead).

The only [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geocoding/basics/alternative-searches.htm) that I have found about this says:

> Although finding locations for addresses is a common practice, you can
>   also use locators to find features based on the name of a location,
>   such as a shopping center or business office. Locators also allow you
>   to search based on a code, such as a postal code, census tract, tax
>   ID, parcel ID, or **coordinates based on a spatial reference system**.

I could find no hints about how to use British National Grid rather than geographic coordinates in the Locate pane.  The XY Provider evident in the graphic above seems to be absent from the documentation too.

Comment: Hi, that doesnt really seem to work. For example Eastings/Northings for London, UK are 529841,180528. But I can't locate London using that even though my map is set to British National Grid

Comment: Apply those coordinates to grid tq